# Separación entre paneles Timeline Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estoy intentando reducir la separación entre cada panel, pero no lo logro, solo logré reducir el tamaño de los paneles mas no la separación entre ellos.

Lo que necesito es la mejor forma de mostrar los 7 paneles al mismo tiempo en la pantalla.

Si alguien puede ayudarme muchas gracias.

```css
 .timeline,
 .timeline-horizontal {
   list-style: none;
   padding: 20px;
   position: relative;
 }

 .timeline:before {
   top: 40px;
   bottom: 0;
   position: absolute;
   content: " ";
   width: 3px;
   background-color: #eeeeee;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -1.5px;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   position: relative;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item:before,
 .timeline .timeline-item:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item:after {
   clear: both;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge {
   color: #fff;
   width: 54px;
   height: 54px;
   line-height: 52px;
   font-size: 22px;
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   top: 18px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -25px;
   background-color: #7c7c7c;
   border: 3px solid #ffffff;
   z-index: 100;
   border-top-right-radius: 50%;
   border-top-left-radius: 50%;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge i,
 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge .fa,
 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge .glyphicon {
   top: 2px;
   left: 0px;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.primary {
   background-color: #1f9eba;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.info {
   background-color: #5bc0de;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.success {
   background-color: #59ba1f;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.warning {
   background-color: red;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.danger {
   background-color: #ba1f1f;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel {
   position: relative;
   width: 46%;
   float: left;
   right: 16px;
   border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
   background: #ffffff;
   border-radius: 2px;
   padding: 20px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
   box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel:before {
   position: absolute;
   top: 26px;
   right: -16px;
   display: inline-block;
   border-top: 16px solid transparent;
   border-left: 16px solid #c0c0c0;
   border-right: 0 solid #c0c0c0;
   border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
   content: " ";
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-title {
   margin-top: 0;
   color: inherit;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-body>p,
 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-body>ul {
   margin-bottom: 0;
   
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-body>p+p {
   margin-top: 5px;
   
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item:last-child:nth-child(even) {
   float: right;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item:nth-child(even) .timeline-panel {
   float: right;
   left: 16px;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item:nth-child(even) .timeline-panel:before {
   border-left-width: 0;
   border-right-width: 14px;
   left: -14px;
   right: auto;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal {
   list-style: none;
   position: relative;
   padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
   display: inline-block;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal:before {
   height: 3px;
   top: auto;
   bottom: 26px;
   left: 56px;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal .timeline-item {
   display: table-cell;
   height: 280px;
   width: 20%;
   min-width: 320px;
   float: none !important;
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   vertical-align: bottom;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal .timeline-item .timeline-panel {
   top: auto;
   bottom: 64px;
   display: inline-block;
   float: none !important;
   left: 0 !important;
   right: 0 !important;
   width: 50%;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal .timeline-item .timeline-panel:before {
   top: auto;
   bottom: -16px;
   left: 28px !important;
   right: auto;
   border-right: 16px solid transparent !important;
   border-top: 16px solid #c0c0c0 !important;
   border-bottom: 0 solid #c0c0c0 !important;
   border-left: 16px solid transparent !important;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal .timeline-item:before,
 .timeline-horizontal .timeline-item:after {
   display: none;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal .timeline-item .timeline-badge {
   top: auto;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 43px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; overflow-y: auto;">
      <ul class="timeline timeline-horizontal">
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge success"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title"> Vehículo</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>---</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge success"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">1</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>26039 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge success"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title"> 2</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>26037 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge success"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">3</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>26016 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge warning"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">4</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>---</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge warning"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">5</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>---</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge warning"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">6</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>---</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas cambiar el `width` a 14% y el `minwidth` a 230px;

```css
.timeline,
 .timeline-horizontal {
   list-style: none;
   padding: 20px;
   position: relative;
 }

 .timeline:before {
   top: 40px;
   bottom: 0;
   position: absolute;
   content: " ";
   width: 3px;
   background-color: #eeeeee;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -1.5px;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   position: relative;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item:before,
 .timeline .timeline-item:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item:after {
   clear: both;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge {
   color: #fff;
   width: 54px;
   height: 54px;
   line-height: 52px;
   font-size: 22px;
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   top: 18px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -25px;
   background-color: #7c7c7c;
   border: 3px solid #ffffff;
   z-index: 100;
   border-top-right-radius: 50%;
   border-top-left-radius: 50%;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge i,
 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge .fa,
 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge .glyphicon {
   top: 2px;
   left: 0px;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.primary {
   background-color: #1f9eba;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.info {
   background-color: #5bc0de;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.success {
   background-color: #59ba1f;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.warning {
   background-color: red;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.danger {
   background-color: #ba1f1f;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel {
   position: relative;
   width: 46%;
   float: left;
   right: 16px;
   border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
   background: #ffffff;
   border-radius: 2px;
   padding: 20px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
   box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel:before {
   position: absolute;
   top: 26px;
   right: -16px;
   display: inline-block;
   border-top: 16px solid transparent;
   border-left: 16px solid #c0c0c0;
   border-right: 0 solid #c0c0c0;
   border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
   content: " ";
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-title {
   margin-top: 0;
   color: inherit;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-body>p,
 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-body>ul {
   margin-bottom: 0;
   
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-body>p+p {
   margin-top: 5px;
   
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item:last-child:nth-child(even) {
   float: right;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item:nth-child(even) .timeline-panel {
   float: right;
   left: 16px;
 }

 .timeline .timeline-item:nth-child(even) .timeline-panel:before {
   border-left-width: 0;
   border-right-width: 14px;
   left: -14px;
   right: auto;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal {
   list-style: none;
   position: relative;
   padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
   display: inline-block;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal:before {
   height: 3px;
   top: auto;
   bottom: 26px;
   left: 56px;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal .timeline-item {
   display: table-cell;
   height: 280px;
   width: 14%;
   min-width: 230px;
   float: none !important;
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   vertical-align: bottom;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal .timeline-item .timeline-panel {
   top: auto;
   bottom: 64px;
   display: inline-block;
   float: none !important;
   left: 0 !important;
   right: 0 !important;
   width: 160px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal .timeline-item .timeline-panel:before {
   top: auto;
   bottom: -16px;
   left: 28px !important;
   right: auto;
   border-right: 16px solid transparent !important;
   border-top: 16px solid #c0c0c0 !important;
   border-bottom: 0 solid #c0c0c0 !important;
   border-left: 16px solid transparent !important;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal .timeline-item:before,
 .timeline-horizontal .timeline-item:after {
   display: none;
 }

 .timeline-horizontal .timeline-item .timeline-badge {
   top: auto;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 43px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; overflow-y: auto;">
      <ul class="timeline timeline-horizontal">
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge success"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title"> Vehículo</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>---</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge success"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">1</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>26039 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge success"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title"> 2</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>26037 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge success"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">3</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>26016 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge warning"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">4</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>---</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge warning"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">5</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>---</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-item">
          <div class="timeline-badge warning"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">6</h4>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>---</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```